# How do I write text and timestamps to a file from a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, scripting

I want to write an interactive Windows script that takes a users name and username and saves it to a file for user records that notes their information and the time they entered it. Can anyone teach me how I would go about this.

```
  @echo off
    ECHO Welcome to the User Records System
    SET /P <name>=[Please enter you full name.]
    SET /P <uName>=[Please enter your username.]
    ECHO %name%
    ECHO %uName%
```

I'm writing this in notepad++ because I assumed it would make my life easier.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add to the question , the codes you have come up with so far

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `%time%` variable for the time, and `>>` to append to a file.

```
@echo off
ECHO Welcome to the User Records System
SET /P <name>=[Please enter you full name.]
SET /P <uName>=[Please enter your username.]
ECHO %name% >>C:\details.txt
ECHO %uName% >>C:\details.txt
ECHO %time% >>C:\details.txt
```

Modify however you wish!

Comment: Great, does this automatically create a file called details.txt?